# MySQL fulltext search over multiple rows

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table called `essays` which has a 1-to-M relationship with a table called `paragraphs`. Therefore, the `paragraphs` table has foreign key pointing to `essay`.

The current problem I have is that, if I make a search, MySQL will look at each individual paragraph, but has no idea that multiple paragraphs can point to the same book.

My fulltext search looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, 
 MATCH(essays.title) AGAINST('my search') as tscore,
 MATCH(paragraphs.content) AGAINST('my search') as cscore
FROM essays 
INNER JOIN paragraphs ON paragraphs.essay_id = essays.id
WHERE 
 MATCH(essays.title) AGAINST('my search')
 OR MATCH(paragraphs.content) AGAINST('my search')
ORDER BY (3 * tscore + cscore) DESC
```

Is there a way to make MySQL search for something across all the paragraphs of an essay and just return that essay?

Comment: Would using `GROUP BY essays.id` help?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
SELECT essays.id, essays.title,
   MATCH(essays.title) AGAINST('my search') as tscore,
   MATCH(paragraphs.content) AGAINST('my search') as cscore
FROM essays 
   INNER JOIN paragraphs ON paragraphs.essay_id = essays.id
GROUP BY essays.id
   HAVING tscore > 0 OR cscore > 0
ORDER BY (3 * tscore + cscore) DESC;
```

You could also use WHERE clause instead of HAVING, but then you need to:

```
SELECT essays.id, essays.title,
   MATCH(essays.title) AGAINST('my search') as tscore,
   MATCH(paragraphs.content) AGAINST('my search') as cscore
FROM essays 
   INNER JOIN paragraphs ON paragraphs.essay_id = essays.id
WHERE 
   MATCH(essays.title) AGAINST('my search')
   OR MATCH(paragraphs.content) AGAINST('my search')
GROUP BY essays.id
ORDER BY (3 * tscore + cscore) DESC;
```

Note that you should not use `SELECT *` when using `GROUP BY` because of unwanted aggregation issues that might pop up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is at least close to what I first tried too! I get `Unknown column 'tscore' in 'where clause'`, and if I delete the `WHERE` clause, I get `Error Code: 1055. Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'uni.paragraphs.content' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Comment: Updated my answer with the right syntax using HAVING instead of WHERE.. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I get the same thing, unfortunately. I will come back to this one when I get the time and post an update. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Probably because you use `SELECT list`, is that another column? When using group by you have to specify how you want the multiple rows aggregated, for example using `GROUP_CONCAT()`